# set Http Headers for all subsequent url calls in web view iOS + Swift 3

Tags: ios, web, view, swift3

I am trying to load a URL in a web-view. I have to set the Http Headers for the url dynamically. For the first url load request the http headers is set properly but I don't think the headers is set for the subsequent web-veiw calls. Any one please let me know how to pass the http headers for all subsequent web view calls.

```
var webUrl = "https://example.com"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:WebUrl)! as URL)
request.setValue("xxxxxxxx",forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization")
webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/yarshure/NSURLProtocolExample

The above example allowed me to intercept all the request made by webview so that I can add the HTTP headers.